# Release apache http connection to pool when response is null

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, hystrix

We am using apache http client to connect to external helper systems. And we are using Hystrix commands to execute the http requests. 
When these requests take more time to respond and time is more than Hystrix timeout, Hystrix will return the fallback which is null.

Since it is returning null Http response can not be consumed using `EntityUtils` and hence connection is not returned to connection pool.

We have tried using `httpGet.releaseConnection`. But it appears to be not working.

What is the best way to release connection back to pool when http request takes more time to response than anticipated time?

Hystrix fall back

```
@Override
protected CloseableHttpResponse getFallback() {
    logger.error(" Returning fallback");
    return null;
}
```

Code to execute REST query and process result

```
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = //Get client from pool
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(serverPath);
HystrixTestCommand testCommand = new HystrixTestCommand(httpClient, httpGet);
CloseableHttpResponse httpResponse = testCommand.execute();
if (httpResponse != null
        && httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
    //Consule entity
} else if (httpResponse != null 
        && httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
    //Consule entity
} else if(httpResponse == null){
    // When http request not responded within anticipated time
    httpGet.releaseConnection();
    logger.info("Release connection");
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HttpClient automatically releases all resources in case of any exception thrown in the course of request execution or in case of request being aborted by the caller. You can do `HttpGet#abort` to terminate the request and ensure de-allocation of resources associated with it.

Comment: It appears to be releasing the connection after abort. Thanks

Comment: But what is the difference between releaseConnection and abort methods?
All they do reset some Atomic variables. How implementation dependent on them?

Comment: They pretty much do the same thing as far as resource management is concerned. #abort method however leaves the request object in an invalid (aborted) state, whereas #releaseConnection and #reset methods reset the request to its initial state, which enables its re-use and re-execution.

Comment: Perfect. Now it is clear. Thanks again for clarifications. 
Are these differences documented somewhere? Especially when pools are used it becomes necessary that code which is calling http client call all these methods so connection is released to pool